# Set VBA Range Equal to Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a formula in cell C2 of my worksheet where I define a range based on a variety of factors. The value in cell C2 is F13:G65.

I would now like to copy that range using VBA, where VB recognizes the range in cell C2 as the range that it should copy. Keep in mind that the range of F13:G65 will change, which is why I want VBA to copy whatever range I have in cell C2.

Can someone help me define the code to do this?

Comment: `WorkSheet("Blah").Range(Worksheet("Blah").Range("C2").Value).Copy`

Answer (score 2):

### Copy a Range: Avoiding 'Surprises'

```vb
Sub CopyRange()
    
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!
    
    ' Write the range address to a string variable ('rgAddress').
    Dim rgAddress As String: rgAddress = CStr(ws.Range("C2").Value)
    ' Use 'CStr' to convert to string to avoid an error occurring
    ' if the cell contains an error value.
    
    ' Attempt to reference the range ('rg').
    Dim rg As Range
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping (ignore errors)
        Set rg = ws.Range(rgAddress)
    On Error GoTo 0 ' disable error trapping
    
    ' Validate the range.
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "'" & rgAddress & "' is not a valid range address.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Continue, e.g.:
    rg.Copy
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just point to the value in `C2` as the range to copy:

```
Sub CopySomeRange()
Range(Range("C2").Value).Copy
End Sub
```

As Scott said in his comment, you can also specify the `Sheet` if you don't want to use the `ActiveSheet`.

For example, if `C2` is on `Sheet1`, but you want to copy from the `ActiveSheet`, you could use:

```
Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value).Copy
```

You can also shorten it a bit to `Range([C2]).Copy` if you're so inclined:

[image]

Comment: not only can you, but you SHOULD specify the parent sheet of all range objects.  Do not let vba assume the sheet.  It causes more problems than it is worth to skip.

Comment: Depending on the use, this may or may not be the case. For example, if `C2` is on many different sheets (and you always want to use the active sheet), it's worth leaving it off. I am inclined to agree with you in most cases, however.

Comment: no, then specify `ActiveSheet`  Again letting vba assume will get the user in more trouble than it is worth.  Many many questions on this site are due to poor practice of not using the parent sheet. And frankly is the only thing keeping me from upvoting your answer and deleting my comment.

Comment: Why not specify the workbook too then? In every single line of code? While I agree that there are some good habits to get into, explicitly stating `ActiveWorkbook` or `ThisWorkbook` every time you reference a range is a bit tedious over time. There is certainly a time, place, and use case, but using blanket "always do this" statements is for project managers to decide IMO. And I already upvoted your comment which may as well have been the answer 

Comment: And if I think the user will have more than one workbook open I will do that.  programming languages are lousy guessers.

Comment: I agree with you. I've worked with several teams on VBA related projects over the years and I've seen some things that are far worse than not explicitly stating sheets (try globally declaring x, y, and z as an easy example). I try to show different ways of doing things and explain the benefit, but I also try to avoid forcing people to use code styles (especially if it requires more code to get the job done). It's like complaining about `IIF` statements or shorthand if's in C# being "difficult to read." If someone has difficulty reading, but the compiler doesn't, sounds like their issue.

Comment: But I also understand the benefit of being explicit - IMO () if there's subjectivity to it, I try to let people write the code the way they prefer. If I really want to enforce standards, I'd just run a linter.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from.  I do.  And I am not trying to be confrontational, because opinions are just that opinions.  But one last argument for why to use it, at least on this site, those that frequent this tag all see it as a must like using option explicit at the top of the module, it is better to teach the extreme than to let bad habits form.  And they are much more likely to be free with upvotes that conform to their opinions.  I have to leave so if you respond do not take my silence as anger.  Thanks for the discussion.  I always enjoy them.